# Migrate existing data from AWS Kinesis Video Stream to another

Tags: amazon-web-services

There is a KVS stream where we store fragments using producer timestamp.
In some cases, we need to create another KVS stream and migrate existing data into newly created stream.

I have searched for the same over an internet but didn't find any reference to migrate existing fragments data from one KVS stream to another.

We can't even rename the existing KVS stream.

It'd be great if anybody could provide workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

KVS service indexes on both Producer and Service side timestamps. Depending on your application use case you could use one or the other in the reader API selectors.

The more generic question is why to migrate the fragments from one stream to another - perhaps do some processing?

In case of a simple "migration" a customer could create a simple application that lists the fragments, then iteratively retrieves each fragment and issues a PutMedia with the fragment if you don't need to do any processing.

If, however, you need to do any processing, then the customer might chose to use the Parser library https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library to parse out the frames and do some transformation/analytics and later produce into a new stream using any of the KVS Producer assets.

Comment: I've tried reading the fragments bytes (breaking at each fragment transition) and putting them via the put media API and it is malformed during the process such that the tags are not present when you read the fragments at the other end.